# Untagging from a facebook photo by our own thru Graph Api

Tags: facebook, api, tags, photo

In my app I want the user to be able to untag himself from a photo. I have enabled the permissions: user_photos, friends_photos, publish_stream, publish_actions, user_status.

When I tried it I am getting an error as follows:

> {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call."}}

When I try to do the deletion via:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/some_photo_id/tags/user_id?access_token=a_valid_access_token&callback=whatever&method=delete&pretty=0&sdk=joey
```

Is there any other permissions to be added? When I was googling I found a link related to be the same [question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7303028/delete-photo-tag-from-graph-api);
is it facebook restricting to delete a photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photos can only be deleted by the application that uploaded them.

There is also no API for removing photo tags, only for adding and modifying tags

Answer (score 0):

You can delete photo tags from graph api see [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags) for complete detail of photo untag api.

But your application must be a whitelisted app.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @VipulPurohit Do not post link-only questions !